# Можно ли сделать неиспользование возвращаемого значения ошибкой компиляции?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2022.

Можно ли сделать неиспользование возвращаемого значения ошибкой компиляции?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36757742/5045688 - атрибут `[Pure]` навесить вполне рабочий вариант. | А как превратить предупреждение (warning) в ошибку (error) вы уже знаете.

Comment: [C# Compiler Options to report errors and warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings) - ссылка на документацию, если ещё не читали

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо большое за ссылку!